# vlookup with wildcard to file excel

Tags: excel, wildcard, vlookup, vba

I run a simple VLOOKUP using 2 workbooks. This has traditionally been done manually, but now I need to automate the process every month:

I usually use something like,

=VLOOKUP(D1,'[PD1_Book1_15-09-22.xls]Live'!$A:$A,1,0) ..on the current workbook called NW 01-09, worksheet name "Master", cell F1. I then copy the entire function down the column. The end result being a lot of #N/A's which I filter out immediately.

The problem is both workbooks change their name regularly (eg.. "PD**Book1***-**-**.xls, in which case "Book1" is constant and NW **-**, in which case NW is constant)

So with "Live" sheet active on "PD*_Book1_*.xls" I've tried this, but can't get it to work at all.

```
 Sub Lookup()
 myFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 mySheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
 myRangeName = Range("A:A")

 Dim wb As Workbook
 For Each wb In Workbooks
 If wb.Name Like "NW*.*" Then
 wb.Activate
 Exit Sub
 End If
 Next

 Range("F1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,[" & myFileName & "]" & mySheetName & "!" & myRangeName & ",1,0)"

 End Sub
```

I am totally lost on this one, any help would be great. If I can't get it to work on 1 cell, I have no clue how to fill all of them!

The NW workbook will always be open as it's subject to a load of data cleaning via macro before we get to this point. I am happy for the PD**Book1***.xls to be opened now if it's easier. The data for lookup is on worksheet "Live"

I'm new to vba, and think i've bitten off more than I can chew. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub wcard()

Dim k As Workbook 'looper
Dim wbs As Workbook 'source of the data
Dim wbt As Workbook 'target of the data
Dim ws As Worksheet 'source of the data
Dim wt As Worksheet 'target of the data
Dim i As Long 'just a counter
Dim lrow As Long 'variable for the lastrow formula
Dim wnm As String 'helps with the formula


For Each k In Workbooks 'loop through the open workbooks and 
'assign the source and target variables to the correct workbooks

    If k.Name Like "NW*.*" Then

        Set wbt = k

    Else

        If k.Name Like "PD*Book1*.*" Then

            Set wbs = k
        End If

    End If

Next k 'end of our loop

Set ws = wbs.Sheets("Live") 'assign sheets
Set wt = wbt.Sheets("Master") 'assign sheets

wnm = wbs.Name


lrow = wt.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'find the last rows in your master file that has entries 
'(substitute "A" for the column by which you would determine that)

For i = 1 To lrow Step 1 'loop through the rows of your master to put the
'formula in each of them

    wt.Range("F" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & i & ",[" & wnm & "]Live'!$A:$A,1,0)" 
    ' your formula - note that your sheet name and the range for the lookup do not change
    'depending on the workbook, so no need to put them as variables

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! I can kind of follow it. Just. I am getting a runtime 91 object variable not set error at "wbt = k" though. I've looked at the help file, but am not clear about it.

Comment: @Gabbana Sorry, forgot to put `set` - may bad, original post has been edited and fixed

Comment: @Gabbana please accept the answer if it has worked for you. You can do it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Glad I could help